# Create materialized view which refresh on every day

Tags: oracle

Currently the Materialized view which I had created using REFRESH ON DEMAND so in this case I need to refresh MV explicitly using below command:

BEGIN
   DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_DATA');
END;

But now I need to refresh this MV on daily basis so could anyone please help to write this.
I have seen that we can refresh this MV using writing explicit Job or using COMPLETE/FAST REFRESH statement in MV itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, we can't help you write this type of materialized view.  show some work first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [AskTom discussion](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2664480900346253895) might be helpful to you.